# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 - Average StripLine per serie

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, average, reportbuilder3.0

I have a run chart where the X-Axis is time (split in 13 periods, kind of like months but random dates), the Y-Axis is Number of admissions and my group series is the the Financial year. I need to display 2 years at a time, which means that I have 2 series displayed on my graph being that each year has 13 period.

**Goal:** to create a an "avg number of admissions" line for EACH year.

**Current result:**

I went into Y-axis stripline properties, created 2 striplines and in the "IntervalOffset" I wrote the following  but it still gives me a stripline with an average for both years (together), instead of 2 different striplines each with the year's respective average.

`=IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2013, Avg(Fields!Admissions.Value), Nothing)`

`=IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2015, Avg(Fields!Admissions.Value), Nothing)`

My current graph looks like this:
[image]

*Note:* As you can see with the Averages in the table next to it, my graph stripline simply does an average of all the values available, so instead of having Stripline1 at 91.23 and Stripline2 at 81.85, I have only 1 Stripline displaying something like +/-87

**My dataset looks as follows:**

```
Year |  Period   |   Admissions

2015 |   01      |    35

2015 |   02      |    50
```

[...]

```
2015 |   12      |    43

2015 |   13      |    64

2013 |   01      |    61

2013 |   02      |    52
```

[...]

```
2013 |   12      |    45

2013 |   13      |    42
```

Any ideas?

P.S. My only other alternative (that I can come up with) is to create 2 seperate data sets, put filters on each according to the desired, and then use LookUp to insert it into a Stripline?? But it seems to me like an overkill. There has to be something, simpler =/

Thanks!

Comment: It would be useful if you include a sample dataset and your expected result. I think it is possible by adding a Serie in your chart.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta Hi again Alejandro! Here u go, I did the edits, thanks again =')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding two additional expressions to the `Values` pane of your line chart.

**2013 Average:**

```
=AVG(
IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2013,Fields!Admissions.Value,Nothing)
,"DataSetName")
```

**2015 Average:**

```
=AVG(
IIF(Fields!Year.Value=2015,Fields!Admissions.Value,Nothing)
,"DataSetName")
```

Replace `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset.

Comment: Thanks again! Problem solved. I looked into it, and the reason why it works weel now is because the Avg is done on the IIF and not the other way around as I did it initially. By the way, I find it iritating you need to specify the dataset when your funciton is on a graph that already has its source designated... P.S. It worked by adding as value, but it works as well as a Stripline. I prefered stripline in this case, bc this way i don't need to deal with fixing up the Legend of the graph. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to calculate the average in your dataset as a new column and simply add this as new series.

Something like

```
SELECT [Year], [Period], [Admissions],
    AVG([Admissions]) OVER(PARTITION BY [Year]) AS [Avg]
  FROM [MyTable]
```

would give something like this.

```
2015 | 01 | 35 | 48
2015 | 02 | 50 | 48
[...]
2015 | 12 | 43 | 48
2015 | 13 | 64 | 48
2013 | 01 | 61 | 50
2013 | 02 | 52 | 50
[...]
2013 | 12 | 45 | 50
2013 | 13 | 42 | 50
```

Comment: Thanks for ur input, but I admit that I haven't tried it since the other way work. Cheers!

Comment: no problem, it's always better to have more than one way of solving a problem.